# How to I validate the characters in a string in a specific order?

Tags: java

So I'm supposed to use the scanner to read the users employee number and then put that into a method that returns a boolean value. The employee is supposed to have the form DDDDD-LDDDD with the d being digits and l being letters. If the input matches this format I'm supposed to inform the user that they have a valid number and if it doesn't then I have to say it's invalid. I've trying to separate into two substrings to be able to see if they contain digits as well as to see if it contains a letter. I then try to combine these using a loop and if it's in that format the user is told it's valid and if it's not they are informed it's not. Is there any other possible way to check and see if the employee number is composed of digits besides obviously the dash and letter that I can then use to prompt the user if what they wrote is valid? This is only written in Java

Comment: Please give a few examples of the employee number. Also, have you tried any code? Anything specifically with regex?

Answer (score 5):

You can use regular expressions:

```java
final String[] strings = {
    "54321-A1234",    // A valid employee ID
    "012948B9832",    // The dash is replaced with a number
    "39832-30423",    // The letter is replaced with a number
    "24155-C90320",   // A valid employee ID but the last number
};
for (String string : strings) {
    if (string.matches("[0-9]{5}-[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{4}")) {
        System.out.println("The string " + string + " is a valid pattern.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("The string " + string + " is an invalid pattern.");
    }
}
```

This will output

```
The string 54321-A1234 is a valid pattern.
The string 012948B9832 is an invalid pattern.
The string 39832-30423 is an invalid pattern.
The string 24155-C90320 is an invalid pattern.
```

**Explanation:**

- `[0-9]{5}` means "match exactly five digits";
- `-` means "match the character `-` exactly one time";
- `[A-Za-z]{1}` means "match exactly one letter, case-insensitive";
- `[0-9]{4}` means "match exactly four digits";

Note that `[0-9]` can be replaced with `\\d` and that `{1}` is optional, but I've added just for explicitness.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum).  This prompts for the string and if not in proper format, reprompts.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = null;
System.out.println("Please enter string in DDDDD-LDDDD format");
while (true) {
   str = input.nextLine();
    // checks for 5 digits followed by - one letter and four digits.
   if(str.matches("\\d{5}-\\p{Alpha}\\d{4}")) {
      break;
   }

   System.out.println("Please try again!");
}
System.out.println(str + " is a valid string");
```

Comment: I answered your question to address the prompting issue you mentioned.  I also included a link to the JavaDoc on regular expressions.  If  you have any questions, please let me know.